# How are content files for .deb files created?

Tags: package, debian, ubuntu-12.04, build-process

I'm creating a clone of [Cura](https://github.com/daid/Cura), and one major hurdle is creating a custom content file present [here](https://github.com/daid/Cura/blob/SteamEngine/scripts/linux/debian_amd64/DEBIAN/control). If I could get an explanation as to how this file is generated, that would be great. My main aim is to work around the file to provide it some different data.

Currently, upon changing the data and running the package.sh script, I get an error in the Software Centre saying that it's detected a bad package.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the ***content*** file of a debian (or ubuntu) package. A debian package consist on a DEBIAN folder containing a ***content*** file and a postinst file. Other folders contains the real files to install. The content package is just a description of the package as you can see. The lines are pretty self-explanatory :

```
Package: cura  # package name
Version: 14.01 # version number
Section: misc # section of the package
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64 # you can also put all here
Essential: no
Depends: python-wxgtk2.8, python-opengl, python-serial, python-numpy # other packages it depends on
Maintainer: Daid <daid303@gmail.com>
Provides: cura
Installed-Size: 10000 # doesn't have to be exact 
Description: Cura is a full software solution for 3D printing,
aimed at RepRaps and the Ultimaker. It's free software payed for
and maintained by Ultimaker.
```

Can you be more specific on the tools you are using and the error ?

Comment: sorry for taking time to reply. What I had done is that I'd manually edited the file changing details as needed. Is there a utility that is used to create content files, is it auto generated? I'm not sure as to how that works.

Comment: The content of these files is pretty simple so for that it's not very useful. There are many user tools for helping deb packages creation like debomatic or other tools. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/8055/graphical-tool-for-creating-deb-packages for example